# How do I reset to default window sizes in MacOS Safari's Responsive Design Mode?

Tags: macos, safari, preferences

I use MacOS Safari's Responsive Design Mode for web development (`Command-Option-R` or `'Develop'` > `'Enter Responsive Design Mode'` in the menu.

I have "accidentally" changed the largest window size to a random size (should be 1920 x 1080) by adjusting the horizontal and vertical handles. I would like to reset to 1920 x 1080, but it is very difficult to do by adjusting the handles because of the responsiveness of the controls; it's hard to stop on a specific dimension. Unfortunately, that is the only way I can see to do it, as I can't find a reset control or option anywhere?

I have searched the menu options and the almighty Google and can't seem to find an answer? I suspect there is .plist I can remove? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.This setting is written to Safari's preferences, that are located in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` in dictionary by `ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations` key. So if you need to reset all responsive mode settings - just close Safari and delete that dictionary from prefs .plist file with following terminal command:

```
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations
```

Comment: My-MBP:proj michael$ defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations
2018-09-22 16:17:20.229 defaults[9413:941183] 
Domain (/Users/michael/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.

Answer (score 3):

The responsive design mode can be reset by removing the `ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations` in `com.apple.Safari.plist`. The plist file location depends on the versio OS.

### macOS 10.15 Catalina (and 10.14)

- Go to System Preferences → Security and Privacy
- Enable **Full Disk Access** for Terminal
- Run the following command

  ```
  defaults delete ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations
  ```

If full disk access is not enabled, the plist file cannot be found, read or written to.

### macOS 10.13 and earlier

Editing the file can be done using the plist file in: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`