# Where is macOS 10.14 Mojave com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations?

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, plist

Does anyone know where to find the equivalent of `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations` on macOS Mojave? I have the same problem as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288008/how-do-i-reset-to-default-window-sizes-in-macos-safaris-responsive-design-mode) post, but can't find it on recently updated macOS:

This has changed since High Sierra.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The file is in `/Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`

(replace `$USER` with your username).

However to edit it you have to disable SIP. Reboot and hold `Ctrl+R`, open Terminal and type `csrutil disable && reboot`.

Login and edit the file (either manually or using `defaults` command).
Reboot again holding `Ctrl+R` and type to the terminal `csrutil enable && reboot` to enable SIP.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am hoping there is a way to do this without disabling SIP (and enabling after), as that process takes longer than struggling with the little handles to manually adjust the window size. I will leave the question open for now and hope for further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this path. I've been struggling to find it for a few months since this seems to be a new path with Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Finder** - **Go to Folder**, type 
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/`

Open *com.apple.Safari.plist* file with **right-click - Xcode.app**
Change what you want and **Save**

You should be fine.